# Como sair do laço de condição neste cadastro com Mongoose/Express

Tags: javascript, api, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Estava eu aprendendo a como conectar minha API num banco de dados usando MongoDB, então comecei a aprender como registrar usuários e tudo corria bem até me travar num problema que está me impedindo de avançar, pois não estou sabendo lidar.

Eu tenho minha API rodando normalmente, conecta ao banco MongoDb Atlas sem nenhum erro, o problema é que ocorre quando executo estas linhas de código:

``router.post('/create', (req, res) => {
const {email, password} = req.body;

```
if(!email || !password) return res.send({ error: 'Dados Insuficientes!' });

Users.findOne({email}, (err, data) => {
    if (err)  return res.send({ error: 'Erro ao buscar usuário!' });
    if (data) return res.send({ error: 'usuário já registrado!'});

    Users.create(req.body, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return res.send({error: 'Erro ao criar o usuário!'});

        return res.send(data);
    })
})
```

})
``

Ele sempre para no laço de repetição do primeiro if do qual é:

`if(!email || !password) return res.send({ error: 'Dados Insuficientes!' });`

[image: Mostrando que passo pelo body os dados que ele precisa para continuar rodando e ele me retornando esta mensagem de erro do qual está neste laço de condição]

Mesmo que eu popule com dados que precisem, neste caso, do email e password, ele sempre cai nesta condição dizendo que não possui os tais dados. O que devo fazer para que o código venha a rodar sem cair nessa condição mesmo ela existindo? Isto é, poder registrar o meu usuário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade creio que o problema está no postman, o tipo do body da requisição está text e deveria ser Json

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se você configurou o express para receber dados no formato JSON, e se o POSTMAN está enviando os dados no formato JSON, se já está tudo certo com isso, debugue ou use o console para verificar se o body não está vazio.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta atribuir separadamente:

```
    router.post('/create', (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    
    if(!email || !password)
res.send({ error: 'Dados Insuficientes!' })
```

Também não precisa do return no response.

Comment: Infelizmente ainda continua no laço de condição.